# if statement executes even with false condition

Tags: javascript

I've written some code which is a basic up/down voting list. 
https://alasdairjames.github.io/up-down-counter1/

This works absolutely fine, apart from with the last list item. All the other list items up and down vote as they should.

With the last list item, if I 'down' vote it a few times, and then 'up' vote it, even if its counter is lower than its parent prev sibling counter, the if statement somehow still runs.

I've checked through all the code and I can't see where the problem is.

```
//Move it up 
$(".testMoveUp").on("click", function(event){
    // select the counter, increase it
    const counter = $(event.target).siblings(".datasetCounter");
    let counterNew = +$(counter).text()+1; 
    $(counter).text(counterNew);
    //select this and previous counters
    var thisCounter = $(event.target).siblings(".datasetCounter").text();
    var prevCounter = $(event.target).parent().prev().children(".datasetCounter").text();
    console.log(thisCounter);
    console.log(prevCounter);
    //move if appropriate
    if ( thisCounter > prevCounter) {
        var parent = $(event.target).parent();
        var prevParent = $(event.target).parent().prev();
        $(parent).insertBefore(prevParent);
    }
});

//Move it down
$(".testMoveDown").on("click", function(event){
    // select the counter, increase it
    const counter = $(event.target).siblings(".datasetCounter");
    let counterNew = $(counter).text()-1; 
    $(counter).text(counterNew);
    //select this and previous counters
    var thisCounter = $(event.target).siblings(".datasetCounter").text();
    var nextCounter = $(event.target).parent().next().children(".datasetCounter").text();
    console.log(thisCounter);
    console.log(nextCounter);
    //move if appropriate
    if ( thisCounter < nextCounter) {
        var parent = $(event.target).parent();
        var nextParent = $(event.target).parent().next();
        $(parent).insertAfter(nextParent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you make it into a working snippet?

Comment: What do `console.log(thisCounter);` and `console.log(nextCounter);` output when it fails?

Comment: And, please, provide specific steps to reproduce the error, I have tried and can't reproduce it

Comment: @dquijada specific steps to encounter the error:
(1) go to github link
(2) on the 'test 5' list item, click the down button 5 times, bringing counter to 5
(3) click the up button 
(4) the item moves up the list, even though it fails the condition that thisCounter < nextCounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this two lines:

```
var thisCounter = $(event.target).siblings(".datasetCounter").text();
var nextCounter = $(event.target).parent().next().children(".datasetCounter").text();
```

You are getting the text value and comparing it.

The easier way to fix it is just to parse the texts to numbers. Since you are sure they will always be numbers, you can simply add '+' on your comparisons:

```
if (+thisCounter < +nextCounter) {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** remember to add it to both comparisons, not only one

Answer (score 1):

`if (thisCounter < nextCounter)` -- you compare strings here, not numbers.

Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to store numeric values in `thisCounter` and `nextCounter`:

```
var thisCounter = parseInt($(event.target).siblings(".datasetCounter").text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

String `"9"` is greater than string `"10"`. Make sure to convert your values to numbers before comparing them.